# Ubuntu 19.10 Startup really slow and stuck on Starting Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots

Tags: boot, nvidia

I just installed ubuntu 19.10 and I'm having a hard time to get it to work properly. First I had to add the `nomodeset` to the grub options to get it to boot at all (Nvidia GTX card), now it boots but it's very slow.

Everything looks good but then it get's stuck for 1.5 minutes on `Starting Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots`. After this it works as expected, but would be nice to shave this time off every boot.

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 11.201s (firmware) + 2.681s (loader) + 1.703s (kernel) + 10.024s (userspace) = 25.610s 
graphical.target reached after 10.017s in userspace
```

Results of `systemd-analyze time`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's actually stuck there? On my system it runs right after `sddm`. While it looked like I was stuck on this step, I disabled the service and found it was actually sddm failing to initialize my video. I'd put money on it being your display manager that's slow, unless you're actually seeing a timer in the "Starting..." line.

Comment: Actually the source of the fault was quite unexpected: One of the SATA cables connected to an SDD was faulty so the system was fluctuating between either getting stuck for 1.5 minutes or not booting at all. After a lot of trial and error I figured out the cause and everything started running smoothly. I just wish this error, and the one that it threw when it didn't boot, had been more informative. 

Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: I find most boot problems pretty opaque, I'm afraid.